# Finding Employees and Printing Out Their Salaries from Text Files

Tags: c++, io, set, auto, multimap

I am given a file with (employee names|town they are located) and another file (employee names|salaries). The program asks the user for the town. I read in each file into an multimap and later read in the employees from the particular town (key) into a set and iterate through the set (for loop) and I have a nested for loop iterating through the map and printing out the employee:salary if the the set iterator==the map iterator. I am having trouble with getting all of the output that I should, however. For example, if I type Wax, Joshua Hammer is printed and it skips to Joshua Hartsek without printing Joshua Hamann. Also, for the city, Nonesuch, I get no output, but I should get 3 names and salaries. For Louisville I get 3341 names and salaries, but I only get 3,341, but I should get 13,562. I don't know how to add files here (Can we add files) so I am willing to send the exact files I am reading  to you through email.

```
File Snippet (Nonesuch)

Charles Linton|Nonesuch
Mark Holloway|Nonesuch
Wendy Warner|Nonesuch
```

```
% ./prog0.py Louisville | wc -l
13562

% ./prog0.py ville | wc -l
26888

% ./prog0.py Lexington | wc -l
13463

% ./prog0.py Nonesuch | wc -l
3

% ./prog0.py Lou | wc -l
54049
```

```
//This is C++
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str;
cout << "Enter the location: ";
cin >> str;
ifstream addresses;
addresses.open("personnel_addresses.txt");
multimap<string, string>name_address;
ifstream salaries;
salaries.open("personnel_salaries.txt");
multimap<string, string>name_salary;
string name2address,name2employee, address, tmpstr1, tmpstr2, salary;
while(getline(addresses, tmpstr1) && getline(salaries, tmpstr2))
{
    getline(addresses, tmpstr1);
    int pos = tmpstr1.find("|");
    name2address = tmpstr1.substr(0, pos);
    address = tmpstr1.substr(pos+1);
    name_address.insert({address, name2address});   
    getline(salaries, tmpstr2);
    pos = tmpstr2.find("|");
    name2employee = tmpstr2.substr(0, pos);
    salary = tmpstr2.substr(pos+1);
    name_salary.insert({name2employee, salary});
}
    set<string>employees;
    int k=0;
    for(auto it = name_address.lower_bound(str); it != end(name_address) && it->first.compare(0, str.size(), str) ==0; it++)
    {
        employees.insert(it->second);
    }   
        for (auto i = employees.begin(); i != employees.end(); i++)
        {
        //  if(*i == "Joshua Hamann")
        //      cout << *i;
            for(auto it = name_salary.begin(); it != name_salary.end(); it++)
            {

                if(*i == it->first)
                {
                cout << *i << ":" << it->second << "\n";
                break;
//              k++;
                }  
            }
        }
        cout<<k;
addresses.close();
salaries.close();
return 0; 
}
```

EDIT: My problem was simple and was fixed with using .begin() and .end() to iterate over the multimap name_address and finding each name with .substr(). Also my while loop was incorrect. I should have read each file separate from each other.

```
while(getline(addresses, tmpstr1))
{
    int pos = tmpstr1.find("|");
    string name2address = tmpstr1.substr(0, pos);
    string address = tmpstr1.substr(pos+1);
    name_address.insert({address, name2address});
}   
while(getline(salaries, tmpstr2))
{
    int pos = tmpstr2.find("|");
    string name2employee = tmpstr2.substr(0, pos);
    string salary = tmpstr2.substr(pos+1);
    name_salary.insert({name2employee, salary});
}
```

```
    for(auto it = name_address.begin(); it != name_address.end(); ++it)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < it->first.length(); ++i)
        {   
            string tmpstr3 = it->first.substr(0 + i, str.length());
            if(str == tmpstr3)
            {
               employees.insert(it->second);
               break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you reduce your input files to something small enough to post here (hopefully something between 5-10 lines) and still reproduce the issue and then [edit] them into your question?

Comment: @scohe001 I added a snippet.